# Is there a higher order function to avoid fire on render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function

```
const onClick = (param) => console.log(param)
```

and need to use it like:

```
<Button onClick={onClick(value)} />
```

But it fires on render, how I can change function into higher order function to use it like that?

Comment: `const onClick = (param) => () => console.log(param)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where value is coming from but like this?

```
<Button onClick={() => onClick(value)} />
```

Which could be shifted to

```
const logOnClick = (msg) => () => console.log(msg);

<Button onClick={logOnClick(value)} />
```

Comment: Its syntax that I am trying to avoid

Comment: Added as @trincot suggested

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const Ho = (data) => {
    return () => {
      console.log('Something');
    };
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <button onClick={Ho('data')}> Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Link -https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mxcbvq?file=src/App.js

Comment: Better to wrap it React.useCallback

Comment: Yeah  that would be a correct approach, but that would redirect the query to different direction.

Comment: If it works, I will go with this approach.